# Android - How to bring notification tray for few seconds in front

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have implemented the below code inside onMessageReceived of FCM Message service to show notification to the user when the app is foreground.

Notification is successfully raised and shown in the tray properly.
But , my requirement is , when the app is foreground the notification tray to come in front for few seconds and then it has to hide by default. How to achieve this?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
 NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(2 , notificationBuilder.build());
```

Thanks

Comment: Did the answer helped you!?

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to show the notification tray programmatically, do this:

```
Object sbservice = getSystemService( "statusbar" );
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
Method showsb;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
    showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expandNotificationsPanel");
}
else {
    showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
}
showsb.invoke( sbservice );
```

You also need to add the following permission to Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

Answer (score 0):

set notification priority to Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH or Notification.PRIORITY_MAX